Height gradient generation from height map,using compute shader has weird artifacts
I am trying to generate the height gradient (the slope) for a heightmap of mine using a compute shader in Unity, and the result has weird ringing artifacts and I completely lost what could be wrong. I thought about it being a precision issue, but increasing the magnitudes of the height values or moving to doubles from floats didn't solve the issue...
Height map:

Resulting gradient map, with values of the Y axis in the green channel pictured here:
I also exported the texture to disk to check in Photoshop, and the artifacts are also there so this isn't a display issue...
My compute shader is super simple:
SamplerState samplerInput
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_LINEAR_MIP_NEAREST;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

float3 calcHeightandGrad(int posX, int posY)
{
    float x = posX;
    float y = posY;
    float res = 2048 - 1;
    double sample = Input.SampleLevel(samplerInput, (float2(x, y) / res), 0).x * 100;
    double topSample = Input.SampleLevel(samplerInput, (float2(x, y - 1) / res), 0).x * 100;
    double rightSample = Input.SampleLevel(samplerInput, (float2(x - 1, y) / res), 0).x * 100;
    
    double dx = rightSample - sample;
    double dy = topSample - sample;
    
    return float3(sample, dx, dy);
}


How do you generate the source texture you're sampling here?

That particular one is simply perlin noise multiplied by a radial fallof. The values are in the 0-1 range.
The heightmap also gets generated in a compute shader.

You might get better results computing the gradient directly in the same function that computes the heightmap. It adds only a small amount of arithmetic to a Perlin noise function to return the analytical gradient at the same time, saving you significant memory bandwidth writing and reading it back to compute partial differences.

I might want to layer multiple compute layers for variation, and in that case I am back to computing the gradient from a hightmap.
And I also don't see how computing the gradient directly in the same function would get rid of the artifacting, cause it would calculate with exact same values...

No it wouldn't, because it's not computing partial differences at all, it's evaluating the derivative. You can evaluate the derivative even when blending together multiple layers.

Okay so no solution to my artifacting?

What I have described is the solution strategy I would pursue.
